# Jar stopped executing

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this bizarre problem. My application was running perfectly so many times I executed it, but suddenly yesterday it started throwing this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 3 more
```

Many say that the problem might be some compatibility issues between the java version of the compile machine (under Eclipse i am using `Java-8-Oracle J2SE-1.5`) and the execution machine, in this case a VM using

```
>$java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

This looks ok to me.

**EDIT:**
Solved!
It turned out that the problem had nothing to do with the `apache-httpclient.jar`. The problem was that my root directory was getting low on free space. When i tried to re run this, instead of the previous error I got `Insufficient space for shared memory file` so by deleting /temp things got working.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `apache-httpclient.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it.

Comment: but how could it possible work one day and stop the next?

Comment: @SkarosIlias Hard to say without seeing code. someone has delete the jar?

Comment: delete the jar from where? Isnt it included in the executable jar i create?

Comment: @SkarosIlias I do not know, i can not see your jar, i do not see how you start it ...

Comment: ok this is interesting. what do you mean you dont see how i start it? I just export the project from within Eclipse, using the `Package required libraries into generated JAR` option. Anyway, will try to add the jar